# How to find occupancy/vacancy rates of apartments

Tags: usa, real-estate

According to https://www.apartmentdata.com/databases/marketlineADSonline_TXAU.pdf the Apartment Occupancy rate in Austin, TX is just over 90%. My question is...  How did they make this determination? Is there some public data set that contains this data? Is there a way, using a free or paid data set, to determine the occupancy / vacancy rate of a particular apartment complex?